# Add PyTest fixtures to a test class using dependency injection

Tags: python, dependency-injection, pytest, fixtures

I'm using Python 3 with PyTest and have defined a number of fixture objects in `conftest.py`. The problem I'm having is that there are some fixture objects that will be needed by every test case. Requesting these fixture references in all test cases results in a lot of repeated boilerplate code.

Here's the fixture in `conftest.py`:

```py
def fixtureA(request):
    _fixture = FixtureA()
    # initialize the fixture, do stuff with request
    return _fixture
```

Here's the current test class, where I want to remove all fixtures from arguments for readability:

```py
class TestSomeFeature(BaseTest):

    def test_some_function(self, fixtureA, fixtureB, fixtureC):
        fixtureA.doSomething()
        # execute test case, do stuff with other fixtures     

    def test_some_other_function(self, fixtureA, fixtureB, fixtureC):
        data = fixtureB.getData()
        # execute test case
```

This approach works, but I'd like to find a way to use dependency injection (or similar) to automagically inject the fixtures in `BaseTest` attributes without having to specify them in every test case's argument list. I'm looking for something like this, but open to any other suggestions:

```py
class BaseTest:
    # This does not work, since pytest does not allow constructors in the test class
    def __init__(fixtureA, fixtureB, fixtureC):
        self.fixtureA = fixtureA
        self.fixtureB = fixtureB
        self.fixtureC = fixtureC
```

I want the test class to look like this, much cleaner!

```py
class TestSomeFeature(BaseTest):

    def test_some_function(self):
        self.FixtureA.doSomething()
        # execute test case

    def test_some_other_function(self):
        data = self.FixtureB.getData()
        # execute test case
```

Comment: If you need it it all tests, just use `autotest=True`. If you need it it in all tests of a test class (or base class), put it in that class and set `autouse=True`. Maybe I didn't understand the usage...

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks for your feedback. If anything isn't clear, I'll try to clarify, then you can upvote the question if it is complete and clear. I added an EDIT explaining why I don't think autouse can be used, as well as a code snippet at the  beginning showing how a fixture is returning a reference to an object, not just executing a block of code.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I also am not clear on your suggestion: are you saying I should move the fixture code from `conftest.py` to the base class? Can you do that in PyTest? I thought fixtures had to be in `conftest`.

Comment: I put it in the answer, I hope that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: (Aside: we try not to add answer material in questions here. However, self-answers are welcome, so if you want to offer a final solution that builds upon a provided answer, making an answer post is preferable to a question edit. I've posted that for you as Community Wiki; if you would like to post it yourself, please do so, and let me know, so I can delete the CW copy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can define fixtures both in `conftest.py` and in test classes. The difference is visibility: if you define a fixture in a `conftest.py`, it is visible to all tests on the level of that `conftest.py` file and below. If you define it inside a test module, it is visible in this module only. If you define it inside a test class, it is visible in this class and derived classes.

Also note that you can use `autotest=True` also if you return a value - you just have to reference the fixture in the respective tests. You can also save the fixture value in a variable. Here is a simplistic example for both cases if you are are using a base class:

```py
class TestBase:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def fixture1(self):
        self.value1 = 1  # save the fixture value
        yield

    @pytest.fixture
    def fixture2(self):
        yield 2  # return the fixture value - fixtue has to be referenced
        # autouse can still make sense if there is setup/tearDown code,
        # and the fixture must not be referenced in all of the tests

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def fixture3(self):
        self.value3 = 3
        yield 3  # do both - can be used either way


class TestDerived(TestBase):
    def test_1(self):
        assert self.value1 == 1

    def test_2(self, fixture2):
        assert fixture2 == 2

    def test_3_1(self):
        assert self.value3 == 3

    def test_3_2(self, fixture3):
        assert fixture3 == 3
```

Note that you get the *fixture value*, not the fixture itself, if you refer to the fixture, so there is no need (and it is not possible) to *call* the fixture - instead you directly use the value returned by the fixture.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the tip. The IDE complains about not assigning the attribute in __init__ but I can live with that.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is based on the answer from @MrBeanBremen.

You can create a fixture in the base class called `injector`, whose sole responsibility it is to inject fixtures from `conftest` into the base class:

```py
class BaseTest:

    @fixture(autouse=True)
    # noinspection PyAttributeOutsideInit
    def injector(self, fixtureA, fixtureB):
        self.fixtureA = fixtureA
        self.fixtureB = fixtureB
```

All  test classes that inherit from `BaseTest` can now access the fixtures without any boilerplate code. A constructor cannot be used in `BaseTest`, since PyTest will ignore the test class completely if a constructor is implemented. PyCharm will generate a weak warning, since we're defining attributes outside `__init__`, but that can be suppressed using the `noinspection` comment.